# React ES5's alternative way of doing ES6's setstate callback?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to force react to perform `setstate` synchronously by passing a callback function to `setstate`

I have done my research on SO and found out that we can do something like

```
this.setstate({state:value}, () => {function()})
```

However, since ES5 does not have the arrow function, how should I pass a callback in setstate?

I have tried  `this.setstate({state:value}, function())` but it did not do what I wanted it to do.

Additionally, is there any more ideal way of forcing react to perform setstate synchronously?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: What exactly did you do that did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force `setState` to be synchronous because React will sometimes batch multiple updates together to prevent too many updates happening at once.

If you pass a callback as the second argument, then React will call it *after* the component's state has been updated.

```
this.setState({ key: value }, function() {
  // this.state is updated
});

// this.state might not be updated
```

The other option is to instead use `componentDidUpdate` to wait for any `setState` changes, which is a better solution if you always want to update after *any* state changes.

Just generally, React can't tell whether you passed an arrow function or a regular function as a parameter, so the behaviour won't change based on whether you're using ES6 or ES5 syntax.

Comment: So componentDidUpdate will always be called only after setState is finished? So is it exactly what the second argument is doing? can you elaborate the difference?

Comment: Similarly, `componentDidUpdate` may be called after multiple `setState` calls have been batched into one update.

Comment: I don't think there's any official way to run some update after _every_ time `setState` is called. You could try to wrap `setState` with another method, or patch it entirely, but remember that you'll be working outside the proper lifecycle methods and that the state won't have actually updated.

Comment: It is more complicated in my case. I am trying to passed a child component's function as a callback function, so componentDidUpdate does not work in this case since it only receives two arguments: prevProps and prevState and it cant receive the callback function as a argument

Comment: You're passing a child component method to the callback for the parent's `setState` call? That sounds like an anti-pattern to me. Better to have the parent update the child by passing new props, rather than through indirection of callbacks.

That said, there's no reason you can't access that child inside `componentShouldUpdate`. E.g. `prevProps.children[0].props.someFn`.